# Create and use global variable without the 'global' keyword?

Tags: php, variables, global-variables

As of now I create a variable like this in a file that's loaded on all pages:

```
<?php

  add_action( 'parse_query', 'my_global_vars' );
  function my_global_vars() {

    /* CUSTOM GLOBAL VARIABLES */
    $variable_name = get_query_var('category_name');

  }

?>
```

And every time I want to use it (in other files), I must do it like this:

```
<?php

  global $variable_name;

  if( $variable_name = 'news' ){

    // Do something

  }

?>
```

And when I need to use the variable multiple times in the same file, I add `global $variable_name;` at the top of the file, and simply use `$variable_name` in rest of the instances.

But as the number of variables increase, I find it harder to manage the list of `global $variable_name`s at the top of all files.

Is there a way to define a variable as global at the time of creation and simply use `$variable_name` everywhere else?

**EDIT:** One way is to define variable like this:

```
<?php

  add_action( 'parse_query', 'my_global_vars' );
  function my_global_vars() {

    /* CUSTOM GLOBAL VARIABLES */
    global $variable_name;
    $variable_name = get_query_var('category_name');

  }

?>
```

And use it like using `$GLOBALS[]` like this `$GLOBALS['variable_name']` elsewhere.

Comment: You should have a look at `Singleton`

Comment: Globals are problem. They break the encapsulation. You should reconsider refactoring this, maybe through an OOP approach...

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos Don't know much about OOP. Could you please drop an example?

Comment: It's hard to give you one example because it's a totally different approach. I'm just suggesting you to try learn it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a lot of global vars is usually bad. It becomes a mess very quickly.

If you really need global variables the best approach is to use [static class variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php). They are just as global as the others, but they enforce better naming and pre-declaration so the end result is somewhat better.

If you really need normal global vars you can also use the `$GLOBALS` variable, it is available in every scope and is basically an array of all the global variables.

```
global $variable_name;
do_something_with($variable_name);
```

is the same as

```
do_something_with($GLOBALS['variable_name']);
```

Comment: Can `$GLOBALS[]` used elsewhere retrieve a variable defined in a function?

Comment: `$GLOBALS` only contains global variables, a variable defined in a function (without `global`) is local, which basically means it is only available during the function execution and will not persist between separate function calls.

Comment: Yes, I meant a variable initialized with global within a function. I've provided an example at the end of my question. Is that a good way to do it?

Comment: In that case it should be accessible. `$GLOBALS` and the `global` keyword both refer to the same variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a static class for this and keep it OOP:

```
<?php
    class GlobalVariables {
        private static $vars = array();

        public static function get($name, $default = null) {
            return (isset(self::$vars[$name]) ? self::$vars[$name] : $default);
        }

        public static function set($name, $value) {
            self::$vars[$name] = $value;
        }
    }

    function foo() {
        GlobalVariables::set('foo', 'oof');
    }

    function bar() {
        var_dump( GlobalVariables::get('foo') );
    }

    foo();
    bar(); //oof
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/juKqUAk6)

---

Alternatively, you can use a Singleton pattern:

```
<?php
    class GlobalVariables {
        private static $instance;

        private $vars = array();

        public static function get() {
            if (empty(self::$instance)) {
                self::$instance = new GlobalVariables();
            }
            return self::$instance;
        }

        public function __get($name) {
            return (isset($this->vars[$name]) ? $this->vars[$name] : null);
        }

        public function __set($name, $value) {
            $this->vars[$name] = $value;
        }
    }

    function foo() {
        GlobalVariables::get()->foo = 'oof';
    }

    function bar() {
        var_dump( GlobalVariables::get()->foo );
    }

    foo();
    bar(); //oof
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/KuJ9xQXf).

Use whichever you find most readable.

```
GlobalVariables::set('key', 'value');
GlobalVariables::get('key');
```

or

```
GlobalVariables::get()->key = 'value';
GlobalVariables::get()->key;
```

---

Completely alternatively, if you hate dynamicness, simply use static variables (this, however, requires you to create all variables beforehand):

```
<?php
    class GlobalVariables {
        public static $foo;
    }

    GlobalVariables::$foo = 'oof';

    var_dump( GlobalVariables::$foo );
?>
```

Comment: Unless you're paid by the line this has no advantages over `$GLOBALS`.

Comment: Yes it certainly has advantages, as name conflicts because of globals are much less likely

Answer (score 1):

Using [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) outside a function doesn't do anything. It's meant for inside functions. You can simply remove your `global` statements.

Edit: I suggest that you try to reduce the number of global variables you have by structuring them. Group them into arrays or objects. E.g., instead of `user_name`, `user_id`, `user_is_admin`, prefer `user['name']`, `user['id']`, `user['is_admin']`, then you only have one variable (`user`) to declare as global instead of three.

Comment: Tried that. It wasn't working. (that is, nothing was happening)

Comment: @its_me Are you including all of your files inside functions? Why?

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't notice the mistake in my question. Please see the edit. It IS defined inside a function, which is why I am asking the question. Again, apologies!

Comment: @its_me Now it makes even less sense. You're assigning to local variables that will be gone as soon as the function ends, and outside the function you're still using `global` where it has no effect.

Comment: I need to use the function because it's hooked to an action which is required to get the value (the edit should make it more clear). So, `global` isn't supposed to be used to retrieve a variable from a function? Do I have an alternative?

Comment: @its_me `global` doesn't retrieve variables from functions at all. Your `my_global_vars()` function, as shown, **does nothing** (unless `get_query_var()` has side effects). The local variable it assigns to dies when it returns. Using `global` later won't resurrect it.

Comment: Learnt a lot from your comments, and I now realize what I was doing wrong. And thanks for the nice tip (`array` variables). This is what you meant, right? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7443273

Comment: In a script that is included, redeclaring a variable a global is probably the best way to indicate that the variable has been set previous to inclusion. It also helps the IDE realizing this fact, which could be helpful.