# variables declared not passed on

Tags: php, include

Minor issue here ;-)

config.php

```
<?php
   include "functions.php";
?>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
    $string = "1234";
?>
```

datafile.php

```
<?php
     include "config.php";
     echo "String:".$string;
?>
```

Result:
String:

why is $string not passed on?

Comment: Because nothing is included in `datafile.php` ?

Comment: he.. sorry.. Edited..

Comment: Perhaps the files you include are in a different location that the script searches through. Try replacing `include` with `require` and if you don't get a fatal error - you'll be sure that the files are visible and the problem is elsewhere. Otherwise you have set wrong paths in `include`

Comment: One could also at this stage state that using global variables like this is error prone since the global variable might accidentaly be replaced somewhere by someone. You could use the factory pattern to get a config object or function helper object, or perhaps use the singleton pattern? More info on that in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934727/create-and-use-global-variable-without-the-global-keyword).

Comment: agreed on the global use of variables. Perhaps usage of $_GET["string"] in stead?

Comment: $_GET["string"] is just another place for storing your variable globally, not much better really imo. A bit better, but still bad. And you add the risk of soemone adding a get param to your script and having your value overwritten by 'badvalueahackergaveyou'. :)

Comment: yeps.. and just tried it.. didnt work.
This is weird ..

Comment: Found this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#38128
and tried to 
$string_array = $string;
and then 
var_dump($string_array); in datafile.php = NULL

Comment: Seems that it all works fine running scripts from browser. But using CLI/CGI - parameters is not "forwarded"

Comment: FE40: Translation: F*cking Error 40
Class created - inside an if statement! Why.. Oh why..